# Intellij Android preview pane when editing layout xml does not allow me to select other SDK versions

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij13 running Android SDK 19.

There is a bug in the DatePicker component which causes the preview pane to exception rather than showing a preview of the layout.

Posts on the web recommended selecting an earlier SDK version in the preview pane.  A version of 16 is meant to bypass this particular exception.

I've downloaded the SDK 16 using the Android SDK Manager.  However the dropdown in the preview pane does not show version 16.  It only shows 19, and an option to "Automatically Pick Best".

I've ensured that my AndroidManifest has a minSdkVersion which is below 16.

Does anyone know how I can get version 16 showing in this dropdown?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that needed SDK versions are installed using the same SDK Manager, re-add SDK. **IDEA restart may be necessary** for changes to take effect.